# QFileSystemModel and QSortFilterProxyModel don't work well together?

Tags: qt

I found that QSortFilterProxyModel can't filter properly when it works with QFileSystemModel. Sometimes it left NOTHING in the view. Can anyone point out where I'm wrong?

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QFileSystemModel *fsm = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    fsm->setRootPath(".");

    QSortFilterProxyModel *sfpm = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
    sfpm->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
    sfpm->setSourceModel(fsm);

    ui->tableView->setModel(sfpm);
    ui->tableView->setRootIndex(sfpm->mapFromSource(fsm->index(".")));

    sfpm->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(".*cpp"));
    sfpm->setFilterKeyColumn(0);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

In the above code, if I use QRegExp(".*"), it does show all files in current path. You can create a simple project to test this out.

Comment: Which filter expression does not work? What files are in this case in the directory?

Answer (score 3):

I think I've got the right solution for this. I need to subclass QSortFilterProxyModel to do something concerning "source_parent":

```
class MySortFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
protected:
    virtual bool MySortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(
            int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const{
        QFileSystemModel *sm = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
        if (source_parent == sm->index(sm->rootPath())) {    
            return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);
        } 
        return true;            
    }
};
```